# What is the benefit of iterating updates using cursors in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have seen examples of SQL code that use a cursor to loop over a set of rows and update them one at a time. However, if I simply use a SQL UPDATE statement, MySQL seemingly automatically iterates the update across all selected data.

Is there a benefit to using a cursor for this function?

Comment: No benefit at all, except in very rare instances. SQL databases like set-based code, not loops and cursors

Comment: No benefits I can think of, except for a couple of specific cases such as iterating a list and calling a procedure for each row; other than that, they are like running in treacle.